# Explanation Needed For A Javascript Recursion Example

Tags: javascript, recursion

I was going through some examples in Javascript Recursion.

I found the following code in this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Recursion

```
function foo(i) {
  if (i < 0)
        return;
  console.log('begin:' + i);
  foo(i - 1);
  console.log('end:' + i);
}
foo(3);
```

The output the code is:

```
// begin:3
// begin:2
// begin:1
// begin:0
// end:0
// end:1
// end:2
// end:3
```

Can anyone explain the output (specially the values after 'end')?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried just walking through the code yourself, one line at a time? I'd suggest writing a "stack" on the side to keep track of things.

Answer (score 1):

The `end` console logs are the completions of each recursive call:

```
---- Invocation 1 ----
begin:3
        ---- Invocation 2 ----
        begin:2
            ---- Invocation 3 ----
            begin:1
                ---- Invocation 4 ----
                begin:0
                end:0
                ---- Invocation 4 ----
            end:1
            ---- Invocation 3 ----
        end:2
        ---- Invocation 2 ----
end:3
---- Invocation 1 ----
```

Answer (score 0):

First you start with `i = 3`. To console goes `begin: 3`. Next line execute function with `i = 2` and show `begin: 2` et cetera et cetera. If function in another function was executed function's parent can show `end: i`. But you can't see `end: i` when function `i - 1` wasn't done.

More here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29

Answer (score 0):

To understand this code, you need to understand "the stack" in JavaScript. Looking up videos on this topic might help. The stack is like a "to do" list.  Whenever you need to invoke a function, it is put on the "to do" list/ "call stack", until the function is completed.  A function is completed in one of two ways: One) It returns something or Two) It runs completely through to the end of the code inside of the function.

Stepping through the code in your example:

1. the stack is empty.
2. foo(3) is invoked.
3. foo(3) is placed on the stack.
4. Now, the stack looks like this:

> foo(3);

5. JavaScript says, "okay, at the top of my "to do" list, there the function foo(3), so it begins to execute this foo(3):
6. 3 is not less than 0, so the function does not return anything and continues.
7. the console.log('begin: ' + 3) is executed.
8. On the next line, you are invoking a function again.  This is where it gets tricky, so pay attention.
9. At this point, i === 3, so foo(i-1) is foo(2);
10. In order to finish foo(3), JavaScript needs to first carry out the instructions in foo(2) that was just invoked, so foo(2) is placed on the call stack.  So, foo(2) is put on the "to do" list/ call stack, but foo(3) is still there.
11. The call stack now looks like this:

> foo(2);
>   foo(3);

12. JavaScript now starts executing foo(2).
13. 2 is not less than 0, so the code continues.
14. JavaScript does console.log('begin: ' + 2);
15. i - 1 === 1, so, JavaScript invokes foo(1);
16. The call stack now looks like this:

> foo(1);
>   foo(2);
>   foo(3);

17. JavaScript has to complete foo(1) before it can continue with foo(2).
18. This process is repeated until, the call stack looks like this:

> foo(-1);
>   foo(0);
>   foo(1);
>   foo(2);
>   foo(3);

19. Now, lets' step through the code in foo(-1):
20. -1 is less than than 0, so foo(-1) hits its return statement.  It returns undefined.  It does not reach the 'console.log' statement.  Because it returned something, the function is done running.  It is popped off of the top of the "to do" list/ "call stack"
21. the call stack now looks like this:

> foo(0);
>   foo(1);
>   foo(2);
>   foo(3);

22. foo(0) had invoked foo(-1).  Now that foo(-1) has completed, foo(0) can continue.
23. The line of code after having invoked foo(-1) is: console.log('end: ' + 0), so this executes next.
24. foo(0) never hit a return statement, but it did run until the end of the function, so the function is now complete.  It is popped off of the call stack.
25. The call stack now looks like this:

> foo(1);
>   foo(2);
>   foo(3);

26. The code continues in the same pattern as above.  It will continue executing foo(1) until it is complete. It will then go to where it left off in foo(2) and continue running.  When foo(2) has completed, it will also pop off of the call stack.
27. Finally, foo(3) had the instructions to execute foo(2).  Since foo(2) is finished executing, foo(3) can continue with the rest of its code.
28. When foo(3) is complete, the call stack is again empty.

Thus, the console.log("begin: ..) statements are executed on your way up the stack, and the console.log("end: ..) statements are executed on the way down the stack.